# 3D-animated cartoon about a boy who belongs to a tribe on another planet and collects magical powers

Tags: story-identification, magic, cartoon

I loved this cartoon as a kid. It is almost certainly a 3D-animated cartoon, probably with really bad 3D animation.

The story takes place on some different planet. The main character is an orange-haired (well... it looked more like some orange head tentacles, as far as I remember) boy. He has at least one friend. His friend has blue hair. I think it's because he's from a different tribe. The orange haired boy collects magical powers. Can't remember the first one, but the second one has something to do with animal mind control...

That's all I remember. Starting to think this cartoon has never existed. Does anybody know?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, how do you know that the story takes place on a planet other than Earth? And was this a movie or a series?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is ***[Legend of Enyo](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1818912/)*** (2009–2010).

From the narration over the show's opening:

> In a faraway world, the nomadic Doodjie tribe found an orphan boy. They named him Enyo. As he grew, so too did his unique powers. It is Enyo's destiny to lead his tribe to the Hidden Valley. They must overcome great dangers to reach it... some more deadly than others. This is the Legend of Enyo.

- It's a 3D-animated series set on another planet.
- The main character is Enyo, a young member of the Doodjie tribe.
- Enyo has orange tentacle-like things sticking out of the top of his head, while every other member of the Doodjie tribe -- including Enyo's best friends, Ito (a boy) and Agaya (a girl) -- has blue tentacle things on their heads.
- The Doodjie tribe found Enyo abandoned in a basket when he was a baby and adopted him. Enyo had a special amulet with him when he was found and is descended from another tribe.
- Enyo is said to be special and gains new powers as the story progresses, which are linked to his amulet. In the first episode, he gains the power to hear spirits, and in S01E06, "[The Gift](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1960497/?ref_=ttep_ep6)," he gains the power to communicate with animals.

> Enyo's amulet is stolen by a Reptullus. Enyo wants to retrieve his amulet first and finds Quag Naga has stolen the jewel that keeps the Reptullus alive. **When Enyo decides to rescue the jewel and save the Reptullus it results in him getting his amulet back - and receiving a new power from the Snake Spirit - the power to communicate with animals.**

Comment: Oh no, that's it! Thank you so much! It looks even weirder than I remember XD.

Comment: Seriously thank you so much. I've been searching for years.